# Do we need to restart all the tomcat solr nodes after changing the synonyms.txt file in Apache Solr 4.4

Tags: tomcat, solr, lucene, apache-zookeeper, solr4

I am currently using solr 4.4(very old i know) connected to an external zookeeper cluster having 3 zoo Keeper Nodes and having 6 solr Nodes having many cores(10+), if i make a small change to the existing synonyms.txt file of one core how do i apply the changes? is it by restarting all the 6 solr Nodes (`/etc/init.d/tomcat7 restart`)? Is there a simpler way as restarting will take lots of time as there is a lot of files in this,Also do i have to restart the zoo Keeper Nodes as well ?

Comment: As far as I remember you shouldn't need to restart anything; reloading the core should be enough. You'll also have to distribute the changes to all the nodes; as far as I remember (.. again) 4.4 didn't support having these files located in zk. In the current Solr version you'd use the managed synonym graph filter, but that was introduced recently (in this timeline).

Comment: @MatsLindh how do I do second part i.e. distribute the changes to all nodes and which nodes are you talking about zookeeper or solr

Comment: If your synonym file is smaller than 1MB, it can probably be stored in Solr (after reading a bit, it seems to be at least supported on Solr 4.5, so it might have been there from 4.0). Otherwise storing it in a shared directory might be the best way. Try it - upload it to the collection in ZK and see if you can load the file from there.